SAP WebI Function Equivalent to Excel COUNTIF
I need to do the equivalent of an excel COUNTIF where I count all the values of a particular column that equal the value of that column in that row.



Value
Count




One
2


One
2


Two
1



I found this similar question, but the solution there isn't working for me.  It's giving me counts of "1" on every row.
